# 61.39 (a)(6)(i) CFI applicant checkride question

Tags: cfi, checkride

I am taking my CFI checkride on 6/30, the very last day my 2 calendar month endorsement was granted (4/26). In the event the air portion of the checkride cannot be completed by that day and we go up on 7/1 to finish, does the 2 calendar month endorsement still hold since when we began the practical test and endorsements were verified?

For CFI-A there doesn't seem to be any minimum amount of time required 2 calendar months prior unlike say a PPL which is 3 hours dual given 2 calendar months prior. If he has to add another endorsement to be safe, can we just do a little bit of ground and call it a day?

Comment: Yes. Sorry, I was referencing what my logbook states (a123) but (a6i) is really what it pertains to wrt 2 months

Answer (score 1):

**Your question refers to** [14 CFR 61.39(a)(6)(i)](https://www.ecfr.gov/current/title-14/chapter-I/subchapter-D/part-61#p-61.39(a)(6)(i)):

The answer, in my opinion, can be found in [14 CFR 61.43(f)(3)](https://www.ecfr.gov/current/title-14/chapter-I/subchapter-D/part-61#p-61.43(f)(3)) which states:

> (f) If a practical test is **discontinued**, the applicant is entitled credit for those areas of operation that were passed, but only if the applicant:
>
> (1) Passes the remainder of the practical test within the 60-day period after the date the practical test was discontinued;
>
> (2) Presents to the examiner for the retest the original notice of disapproval form or the **letter of discontinuance form**, as appropriate;
>
> (3) Satisfactorily accomplishes any additional training needed **and obtains the appropriate instructor endorsements**, if additional training is required; and
>
> (4) Presents to the examiner for the retest a properly completed and signed application.

*(emphasis is mine)*

Assuming that your test was "discontinued" (not a pass nor a failure) due to weather, mechanical issues, etc., a "Letter of Discontinuance" is issued by the examiner. And, as noted in the sample Letter of Discontinuance shown below, it does not extend the expiration date for the required instructor endorsements.

Here is a  [sample of a "Letter of Discontinuance"](https://fsims.faa.gov/wdocs/orders/8900_2.htm) from FAA Order 8900.2C - General Aviation Airman Designee Handbook, **Figure 7-12**.

*(emphasis and highlights are mine)*

[image]